# Better using a single Map with a custom-made object as value or several Maps with unique "primitive" value?

Tags: java, hashmap, inner-classes

I'm considering refactoring some piece of code I stumbled on, and I was wondering if it's worth it. Here's what I've got: several Maps that take an Enum as Key, and either a String or a Class as Value.

```
private static final Map<MyEnum, String> FIELD_MAP = new HashMap<MyEnum, String>();
private static final Map<MyEnum, String> ALIAS_MAP = new HashMap<MyEnum, String>();
private static final Map<MyEnum, Class> CLASS_MAP = new HashMap<MyEnum, Class>();
```

What's more, all those Maps are "staticly" initialized with static blocks as follows.

```
static
{
    FIELD_MAP.put(MyEnum.VALUE1, "BLOP.ONE");
    FIELD_MAP.put(MyEnum.VALUE2, "BLOP.TWO");
    FIELD_MAP.put(MyEnum.VALUE3, "BLOP.THREE");
}

static
{
    ALIAS_MAP.put(MyEnum.VALUE1, "ONE");
    ALIAS_MAP.put(MyEnum.VALUE2, "TWO");
    ALIAS_MAP.put(MyEnum.VALUE3, "THREE");
}

static
{
    CLASS_MAP.put(MyEnum.VALUE1, String.class);
    CLASS_MAP.put(MyEnum.VALUE2, Integer.class);
    CLASS_MAP.put(MyEnum.VALUE3, Double.class);
}
```

But always the same way, i.e. I have the Map for field names, the Map for the alias names, and the Map for the Classes. I was thinking to use a specific object containing all three fields to merge the three Maps into one only that'd look like this :

```
private static final Map<MyEnum, MyClass> FOREVER_ALONE;
```

The custom-made Class would be a static nested class - because it'd be only used for that purpose - like this:

```
static class MyClass
{
    public String mField;
    public String mAlias;
    public Class mClass;

    /**
     * Actually, all fields are required.
     * So no default empty constructor.
     */
    MyClass(String pField, String pAlias, String pClass){...}
}
```

But before that, I'd like to know if this is really relevant or if I'm just wasting time in doing something equivalent? Is there a performance difference between these two solutions (the existing one and the one I want to develop)?
The actual outerclass is almost 1 600 lines long, so many many many Maps could be merged...

Comment: Using a class grouping the related information would be much cleaner, and would probably be marginally more efficient, since you would need a single map lookup to get all the values at once, rather than 3 map lookups.

Comment: Consider using `EnumMap`. Also consider merging the map values directly into the enum constants. Enum types can have methods and fields, and it seems like these maps hold data that's tightly coupled with each enum constant. If so, the data seems like it belongs directly in the enum.

Comment: @StuartMarks Yes, of course it does. Now I notice that I forgot to mention that enums that are used - they are generated from XSD files... So no possible customization in this sense. =(
Otherwise, you made me discover the EnumMap that I did not know. =)